# not able to save line breaks using JFactory:getEditor

Tags: php, joomla

In `JFactory::geteditor()` I am not able to save line breaks. Is there any way I can make that work ?

Comment: Make sure have the latest version of the Joomla series you're using (1.5.26, 2.5.8 or 3.0.2) as it might contain the latest version of the TinyMCE editor. When you add the line break, click the small "html" icon and see if the code for the line break is there. Then on your website, Inspect the area with Firebug or Chrome Dev Tools and see if that line of code is still there. If it is, then it is most likely the template that is making it appear hidden.

Comment: can I seriously get an answer than people editing my question

Comment: Thanks @Lodder I will try this but i am using joomla 2.5 so.guess version is not a problem

Comment: Seeing as you're using Joomla 2.5, ensure it 2.5.8, which is the latest version of the series ;)

Comment: Actually it's 2.5.7 also I am doing some work on joomla extensions the clients could be using anything in 2.5 series. Is there any generalized solution

Comment: Yes just checked the html and firebug. It shows correctly while saving but when I click on edit and use firebug to inspect it gives me &nbsp